# Sed replace strings starts with special characters

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace strings with sed in `; php_value[date.timezone] = Europe/Riga`

i tried something like this:

```
sed -i 's/; php_value[date.timezone] = Europe/\Riga/; php_value[date.timezone] = America/\Sao_Paulo/g' file
```

Output:
sed: -e expression #1, char 47: extra characters after command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
sed -i 's/; php_value\[date\.timezone] = Europe\/Riga/; php_value[date.timezone] = America\/Sao_Paulo/g' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/K7yK5s).

**NOTE**:

- `[` and `.` are special regex metacharacters and need to be escaped to match literal `[` and `.`, hence, `\[` and `\.` in the regex part
- `/` is a regex delimiter char here, and should also be escaped. To escape `/`, use `\/`. Well, if you use another regex delimiter char, you will have no need escaping `/`, e.g.

```sh
sed -i 's,; php_value\[date\.timezone] = Europe/Riga,; php_value[date.timezone] = America/Sao_Paulo,g' file
```

See the commas as regex delimiters here.